# How to run: apt-get update in order to correct backtrack installation into Ubuntu?

Tags: apt

I´ve just downloaded BackTrack files in order to install their tools into Ubuntu.

I´ve opened then the terminal, and typed: `sudo bash backtrack-tools`

But some stuff seems to be outdated, and appeared this message saying:

> you may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

How may I do that? Should I step myself into the same backtrack folder and type something like `sudo apt-get update backtrack-tools`?

I can´t belive it´s that simple, maybe instead of backtrack-tools I have to type other stuff?

Comment: You should run only `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Run these and reply if your problem still persists

Comment: Thanks! I´ve just run sudo apt-get update and after it, it stills says that I should run sudo apt-get update again. But I´ve run (it´s still running) sudo apt-get upgrade, and see what happens. I think that the error is because of the backtrack package.

Comment: You probably are interested to see this: [Install BackTrack Tools in Ubuntu](http://micksmix.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/install-backtrack-4-tools-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All instructions that I have read seems to be outdated. I mean, wget is unable to resolve repo.offensive-security.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I think] The answer here is that you can´t actually install it inside Ubuntu.

I´ve have to install ubuntu again, and **Backtrack in a Virtual Machine**. That was the only way.

I´m just posting this here in case someone googles it... as a warning.